# Constraint Validation API for input type="email"?

Tags: html, forms, validation, constraints

Using the HTML5 Constraint Validation API for validating a form field with `type="email"`, I noticed that Chrome accepts "aa@a" as correct email address.
What's the purpose of this - is this a bug? Is it bad practice to define a custom pattern?

Comment: In theory addresses with only the top level domain are valid. (On the other hand a single letter is not a valid TLD.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the purpose of this

To not exclude valid email addresses.

> is this a bug

No.  [Here is the definition of a valid email address](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address) which HTML5 compliant browsers should use.  There is an [open defect](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=19117) against that definition, but even if that was fixed `aa@a` would still be a validly formatted email address.  Remember that [email first came about in the mid-sixties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email), we [didn't get DNS until the mid-eightes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), lots of 'right side of the @' things which look a little strange to us now are perfectly valid in these older contexts.

> Is it bad practice to define a custom pattern?

Certainly if your requirements are more strict than 'all validly formatted email addresses' you could, but email validation is an easy thing to get wrong, especially with [all the new top level domains coming online this year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Proposed_domains). If you're really concerned about valid email addresses (as opposed to validly formatted email addresses) then the only solution is to send actual email to the address and confirm it arrives (through some sort of token based confirmation URL the user has to click on).

Comment: Ok WOW thanks for that answer! I know that it's nearly impossible to get **all** possible e-mail formats in a pattern - actually everybody who searched for a flawless e-mail RegEx will know this - so it actually makes sense to be less strict with the opportunity to custom rules. I actually haven't thought about E-Mail addresses in the mid-sixties!